# Jamaican with green card visiting Italy

Tags: schengen-visas, italy, us-residents, jamaican-citizens

As a Jamaican with a USA green card, what document would I need to visit Italy?

Answer (score 2):

US Green Card Holders are not exempt from the visa requirements for the Schengen area. [Schengen Visa Info](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/apply-from-united-states/) has a great article on this. You need to get a visa just like any other Jamaican, but you should also submit a copy of your green card.

> Jamaican citizens need visa for travelling to Italy as tourist. The stay is usually Short stay with a period of 90 days and visa expires in 90 days. Applicant is required to be present when applying for visa and a total of 10 documents are required.

As of December 2019 what you need to submit is:

- Visa Application Form.
- Valid Passport.
- US Residence Permit (Green Card).
- Photo taken within the last three months.
- Cover Letter.
- Rount-Trip Fliht Itinerary.
- Proof of accommodation.
- Means of Subsistence.
- Travel Insurance.

Also:

> ## Schengen Visa Requirements for US Residents and Green Card Holders According to Applicant’s Employment Status
>
> Depending on your employment status in the US, here is a list of additional documents that are required to submit when applying to obtain a Schengen visa in the US:
>
> ### For US employees:
>
> - Employment contract
> - Current bank statement of the latest 6 months
> - Leave permission from the employer
> - Income Tax Return (ITR) form or Certificate of Income Tax deducted at the source of salary
>
> ### For the self-employed:
>
> - A copy of your business license
> - Company bank statement of the latest 6 months
> - Income Tax Return (ITR)
>
> ### For foreign students on F1 visas:
>
> - Valid I-20
> - Reference letter from educational institution (school/college/university) stating that you are in good standing, your major and the expected date of graduation.
> - For foreign students in the US on F1 visas:
> - Valid I-20
> - Reference letter from educational institution (school/college/university) in the US, stating that you are in good standing, your major and the expected date of graduation.
>
> ### For retirees:
>
> - Pension statement of the latest 6 months
>
> ### If unemployed and married to an EU citizen:
>
> - A recent (less than 3 months old) Confirmation of Employment letter from their spouse’s employer stating the position held within the company as well as the starting date,
> - Spouse’s valid passport
> - An officially marriage certificate.
>
> ### Required documents for visa application for underage children
>
> - Original birth certificate
> - Signed travel consent from both parents
> - If one parent is not located in the United States they should submit their signed consent to the Embassy/Consulate of their residing country

Comment: The site you've linked to is generally a poor source.  In addition to vague and potentially misleading statements like "the stay is usually short stay," they have a history of publishing obsolete or plainly inaccurate information.  Official sources are better.